# How to impute missing values with mean from row above and below python?

Tags: python, pandas, row, mean

I have a pandas df looking like this:
[df image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hVIQR.png)

The row I want to impute values for has "-" instead of values and I want these to be replaced with the mean of the values in the row above and below.

Does anyone know how to do that?

Thank you all!

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve] with your sample input as text, not as an image or link, so that we can copy and paste it, and please also show _code_ for what you've tried so far based on your own research so that we can provide more specific help. See also: [How to make good pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace "-" to NaN and use `interpolate` which by default fills missing values linearly. If there is only one missing value, then it would be akin to taking the mean of the top and bottom value of the missing value:

```
df = df.replace('-', np.nan)
df = df.interpolate()
```